# Position a pop-up div relative to the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am facing a problem. I have 10 images in a page. On clicking each, a Pop up will be displayed and the content of the clicked image is loaded from the database and shown in the div (Pop up).

It works fine for the first set of Images(First Row). But when I click on the second and third set of Image rows. The pop up opens , But I have to scroll all the way up and see the Pop up and its contents. (Since the image are at the bottom and the Pop displays on the top of the page)

I tried the following by making the Position: Fixed !important (I got partially succeeded making the Popup Displaying the centre of the View Port. But if the Pop-up contents exceeds the height of the viewport, the rest of the content is hidden and there is no option to scroll down to see more info.)

Please refer this image for more clarity
[image]

## JavaScript

```
// Script for fetching the height of the pop-up based on viewport inner height

$(document).ready(function () {
    function setHeight() {
        windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        $('#panelpopup').css('height', windowHeight);
    };
    setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        setHeight();
    });
});
```

## CSS

```
#panelpopup {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto !important;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fff !important;
    border:solid 1px #333;
    position:fixed !important;
    // I tried absolute first, but the pop up comes on top 
    top:20%;
    left:50%;
    margin:0px 0 0 -400px;
    border-radius:6px;
    z-index:100100 !important;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="panelpopup-wrap"><!-- This is the transparent area around the pop up --></div>
<div id="panelpopup"> <!-- Dynamic Content Goes here --></div>
```

Awaiting your valuable support

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle.

Comment: T-That image is pretty impressive. But if you want us to help you further you need to provide us with the HTML structure, CSS for the popup and body and the JS for it. You can use the [Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show a live example with the problem. If you use jsfiddle please also post the code in your question.

Comment: You can get the number of pixels scrolled vertically with $(window).scrollTop(). Useful for positioning your popup with position:absolute.

Comment: Either the comment above mine or you could set overflow:scroll for the popup

Comment: It's still hard to reproduce the problem for testing. If you want to get a good answer please show a full working example of the problem.

Comment: Just a thought.. Is it possible to position the top based on the viewport rather than the document.

Comment: Hi Gops, in order to do that, without using position:fixed, you would need to know where your viewport is sitting on the page. That is what $(window).scrollTop() tells you. And so you can position an element relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I dug up a very old script that might do the job for you. It scrolls the window untill the right-bottom corner of the referenced element is in view.

Could do with some refining (it was a long time ago ;-) but it still works.

```
function coverdiv(o) {
    var wh, ww;
    var ps = document.getElementById(o).getBoundingClientRect();
    if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
        wh = window.innerHeight;
        ww = window.innerWidth;
    } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        wh = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        ww = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    var diffH = wh - ps.bottom;
    var diffW = ww - ps.right;
    diffH = (diffH < 10) ? (20 - diffH) : 0;
    diffW = (diffW) < 10 ? (30 - diffW) : diffW = 0;
    window.scrollBy(diffW, diffH);
}
```

Just call it with the id of the element.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0tayv5v/1/)

Comment: Sir, that's not solving the issue.. Thank you